# What's a good way to sort strings in ruby so that empty strings are at the end?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby the default sort puts empty strings first.

```
['', 'g', 'z', 'a', 'r', 'u', '', 'n'].sort
```

Gives:

```
["", "", "a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z"]
```

However, it's quite common to want empty strings at the *end* instead.

Doing something like:

```
['', 'g', 'z', 'a', 'r', 'u', '', 'n'].sort { |a, b| a[0] && b[0] ?  a <=> b : a[0] ? -1 : b[0] ? 1 : 0 }
```

works and gives:

```
["a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z", "", ""]
```

However, this isn't very readable and is not very flexible.

Is there a reasonable and clean way to get `sort` in Ruby to put empty strings last? Would it be better to just map to an array with no empty strings, sort, and then pad on the empty strings at the end? Are there other approaches?

Comment: I'd say lexical sorting is *way* more common. I'd also argue it's pretty irrelevant if the sort code is readable; there are times code is just gross. I might use `empty?` and `if` instead to lose the nested tertiary, document and spec it, and then never think about it again.

Comment: *"it's quite common"* -- I'd have to disagree with you there. Interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: I did a benchmark using 1000 random 8 char strings + 75 spaces, then shuffling as the input data to sort (10000x).

SortBy: **29.5s**, Map: **4.5s**, Rotate: **2.6s**, UglyTernary: **24.7s**, PartitionV1: **2.9s**, PartitionV2:  **2.8s**, ReverseCompare: **9.2s**.

The rotate and partition based methods seem substantially faster than the rest.

Comment: @dgsan post the benchmarks and the code as we have no idea what the implementations you used are

Comment: Here's what I used for comparing: https://hastebin.com/ayunudezud.rb (Should probably note I didn't validate the results, just timed them.)

Answer (score 9):

```
arr = ["g", "u", "", "a", "", "r", "n", "z"]

arr.sort_by { |s| [s.empty? ? 1 : 0, s] }
  #=> ["a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z", "", ""]
```

or

```
arr.sort_by { |s| s.empty? ? 255.chr : s }
  # => ["a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z", "", ""]
```

or

```
empty, non_empty = arr.partition(&:empty?)
  #=> [["", ""], ["g", "u", "a", "r", "n", "z"]]
non_empty.sort.concat empty
  #=> ["a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z", "", ""]
```

Comment: We could also go with `arr.sort.partition(&:empty?).reverse.reduce(&:concat)` or `arr.sort.partition {|s| !s.empty?}.reduce(&:concat)` :) but honestly I think your first solution is the best as it needs the fewest methods and transpositions  of the `Array`

Comment: @engineersmnky, there seem to be umpteen permutations. I also had `arr.partition {  |s| !s.empty? }.flat_map(&:sort)` but could not bear the inefficiency of sorting an array of empty strings.

Comment: I agree because I also considered `arr.sort_by { |s| s.ord rescue Float::INFINITY }` but it seems convoluted

Comment: `s.ord rescue Float::INFINITY` wouldn't work properly for 2+ character strings. Also, your second solution is a little dubious - for instance, what happens if `arr = ["a", "\xFF\xFF", ""]`?

Comment: @engineersmnky, did you add something special to your Corn Flakes this morning? (Addressed to your now-deleted last comment.)

Comment: @TomLord very well `arr.sort_by {|a| a.each_char.map(&:ord) << Float::INFINITY}` (fixed from the deleted version)

Comment: Tried using just `#sort`, best I've been able to come up with yet is `arr.sort { |a, b| a.empty? != b.empty? ? b <=> a : a <=> b }`

Comment: What about `arr.sort_by { |c| [-c.size, c] }`

Comment: @SagarPandya That breaks when non-empty strings are of various lengths.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution I can think of is

```
a = ['', 'g', 'z', 'a', 'r', 'u', '', 'n']
a.sort.rotate(a.count(''))
#=> ["a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z", "", ""]
```

`Array#rotate`: Returns a new array by rotating self so that the element at count is the first element of the new array.

So we just rotate by the count of empty strings (`""`)

Answer (score 2):

Just count the number of blanks and then use `#rotate` to move them to the end:

```
sorted = ['', 'g', 'z', 'a', 'r', 'u', '', 'n'].sort
blank_count = sorted.count &:empty?
sorted.rotate! blank_count
```

Comment: Is there any reason that's better or worse than:

    `empty = a.count &:empty?`  
    `a = a.select(&:present?).sort`  
    `empty.times { a.push '' }`  
?

Comment: I'm not sure without benchmarking, but my gut feeling is that it does fewer traversals and allocations.

Comment: @dgsan, note that Ruby does not have a method `String#present?` and there is no Rails tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation, defining a custom `sort` comparison:

```
arr = ["g", "u", "", "a", "", "r", "n", "z"]

arr.sort { |s1, s2| (s1.empty? || s2.empty?) ? (s2 <=> s1) : (s1 <=> s2) }
  #=> ["a", "g", "n", "r", "u", "z", "", ""]
```

Using `s2 <=> s1` is essentially a "reverse sort" - so in cases where an empty string is being compared against, this orders it at the end of the result rather than the beginning.

Comment: I do not get the same result `["a", "", "g", "n", "r", "u", "", "z"]` because this was my first thought but it does not appear to work

Comment: @engineersmnky Really?? Are you sure you copied it correctly? I've just tried this on ruby `2.4.4` and `2.5.1`, and get the same result.

Comment: Tried on `2.3.3` and [Repl.it 2.5.1](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/Arraysort) (copied directly)

Comment: @engineersmnky Hmm, interesting... I reckon it's because of how the `sort` algorithm works - i.e. I was making a false assumption about how all elements always get compared. But I don't *really* know why -- I may even post that as a new SO question! See my updated answer.

Comment: With the original solution (Ruby 2.51): `["g", "", "a"].sort { |s1, s2| puts "s1=#{s1}, s2=#{s2}"; s2.empty? ? (s2 <=> s1) : (s1 <=> s2) } => ["g", "", ".a"]` and prints `s1=, s2=a`, `s1=g, s2=`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not on my machine! I get: `s1=g, s2=`, `s1=, s2=a`. So ruby is using a different algorithm depending on the machine it runs on?!

Comment: At a complete guess, maybe one of our machines is running the algorithm "backwards", due to the order in which the array has been stored in memory?

Comment: @Tom, what machine are you using? Mine's an Apple II+.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Macbook Pro i7 (2017)